# How to print a randomly selected string from Scriptable Objects in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I want to randomly pick an item from a scriptable object and then print the randomly chosen item to the console.

```
 using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;  

   [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Country", menuName = "Country/Country", order = 0)]
   public class country : ScriptableObject
   {
       [System.Serializable]
       public class Item
       {
           public string Name;
           public string Currency;
           public string Capital;
           public string[] City;

       }
       public Item[] m_Items;
   }
```

How do I go on printing the following values to the console?

```
  public Item PickRandomly()
  {
      int index = Random.Range(0, m_Items.Length);
      return m_Items[index];
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the ToString() function for your class like so.

```
 [System.Serializable]
       public class Item
       {
           public string Name;
           public string Currency;
           public string Capital;
           public string[] City;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                string toPrint = "Name: " + this.Name + " Currency: " + this.Currency + " Capital:" + this.Capital;
                if(City != null)
                {
                    toPrint += " Cities: ";
                    for(int  i =0; i < City.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        toPrint += City[i];
                        if(i < City.Length -1)
                        {
                            toPrint += ",";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            toPrint += ".";
                        }
                    }
                }
                return  toPrint;
            }
       }
```

After that you can simply call Debug.Log(PickRandomly());
The output should be something like : "Name : Canada Currency: CAD Capital: Ottawa Cities: Toronto, Montreal, Vancouver.".
You can tweak the output anyway you prefer.